# Finding previous quarter's non null data of a particular column

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Actual vs Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQp3i.png)

Actual:

| Year | Quarter | Value | prev_quarter_val | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FY 2021 | Q1 | 2456 | NULL | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q2 | NULL | 2456 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q3 | 2345 | 2456 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q3 | NULL | 2345 (which is wrong) | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q4 | 3456 | 2345 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |

Expected:

| Year | Quarter | Value | prev_quarter_val | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FY 2021 | Q1 | 2456 | NULL | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q2 | NULL | 2456 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q3 | 2345 | 2456 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q3 | NULL | 2456 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |
| FY 2021 | Q4 | 3456 | 2345 | XYZ | 01-01-2020 |

In the above tables, I have the columns year, quarter, value, name,prev_quarter_val and date.
I have to fill the value column with values from previous quarter. If the previous quarter's value is NULL, fetch the value from the latest quarter and year where it is not NULL.

**What I have tried:**

```
SELECT year,quarter,name,date,value,prev_quarter_val
FROM (SELECT year,quarter,name,date,value, LAG(value,1)
OVER (PARTITION BY date, name ORDER BY year,quarter) AS prev_quarter_val
FROM table t)
```

The problem with my code is it takes the value from the same quarter if the value is present twice

How can I fix the query such that it takes from previous quarter even if its present twice?

Edit: It has to take value from previous year and it is not restricted to year constraints.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I cannot achieve proper formatting with the above link that you have given @a_horse_with_no_name Edit: Nvm, thanks for the heads up, had to replace '+' that were coming up from the editor with '|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with subquery:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table testtable(Year varchar(20), Quarter varchar(20), Value int, prev_quarter_val int, Name varchar(20) ,Date date);
 
 insert into testtable values( 'FY 2021',  'Q1' , 2456 , NULL , 'XYZ' , '01-01-2020');
 insert into testtable values( 'FY 2021',  'Q2' , NULL , 2456 , 'XYZ' , '01-01-2020' );
 insert into testtable values( 'FY 2021',  'Q3' , 2345 , 2456 , 'XYZ' , '01-01-2020' );
 insert into testtable values( 'FY 2021',  'Q3' , NULL , 2345 , 'XYZ' , '01-01-2020'); 
 insert into testtable values( 'FY 2021',  'Q4' , 3456 , 2345 , 'XYZ' , '01-01-2020');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT year,quarter,name,date,value, 
 (select value from testtable tt where tt.year=t.year and tt.quarter<t.quarter and value is not null
 order by quarter desc limit 1)prev_quarter_val 
 
 from testtable t
```

Output:

| year | quarter | name | date | value | prev_quarter_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FY 2021 | Q1 | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2456 | <emnull</em |
| FY 2021 | Q2 | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | <emnull</em | 2456 |
| FY 2021 | Q3 | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 2345 | 2456 |
| FY 2021 | Q3 | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | <emnull</em | 2456 |
| FY 2021 | Q4 | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 3456 | 2345 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d28d4bd58b53425e7f0737ff216f94e8)*

Comment: But it will take only take current year's value, how can I change it to take it from any year where the value is not NULL. Thanks!

Comment: Will concatenating year and quarter work the same as <= ? Thank you so much again! I am a beginner to SQL.